# Images with url

Tags: hyperref, url, hyperlink, hypertarget

I want to show the Linkedin image and address on my CV with url to my Linkedin profile.

The output is required to be work as follows

[image]

I have tried with the flowing MWE but url is not working. I am using PdfLaTex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cleveref}  
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
        \begin{minipage}[l]{0.30\textwidth} 
    \href{www.linkedin.com/in/renjith-v-ravi}{\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{img/LinkedIn_Logo.png}{/in/renjith-v-ravi}}\\
        \end{minipage}

\end{flushleft} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol is missing, thus `\href` does not know, that the partial URL is an HTTP(s) link and assumes a file name. Fix:

```
\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe}{...}
```